# nodejs GetValidationResult and validationErrors

Tags: node.js

```
req.checkBody('first_name', 'First Name is Required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('last_name', 'Last Name is Required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email is Required').notEmpty();

    var errors = req.getValidationResult();

    if(errors){
        console.log('ERRORS');

    } else {

        var newUser = {
            first_name: req.body.first_name,
            last_name: req.body.last_name,
            email: req.body.email
        }

        console.log('SUCCESS');
    }
});
```

Can somebody help me with this? I'm following a tutorial but when I change the `req.validationErrors` into `req.getvalidationresult` I always get the error. But when I did go back to the `req.validationerrors` it says that it is not a function.

Comment: Can you post the link of the tutorial you followed? Also what errors did you get?

Comment: Improved spelling and code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to answer your question specific to a tutorial which is not mentioned. Try following these methods for the same.

//validate.js

```
var util = require('util');

var commonFunction = {};
commonFunction.validate = validate;

module.exports = commonFunction;

function validate(req, res, required){  
    for(var key in required){       
        if(key == 'email'){
            var isEmpty = req.check(key, key+' must not be empty').notEmpty();
            // console.log("isEmpty",isEmpty.validationErrors[0]);
            if(!isEmpty.validationErrors[0]){
                req.assert('email', ' Valid email required').isEmail();
            }
        }
        else {
            req.check(key, key+' must not be empty').notEmpty();
        }
    }
      var errors = req.validationErrors();
      if (errors) {
        var errorResponse = setFailureResponse(util.inspect(errors));
        return errorResponse;
      }
      else{
        var successResponse = {
            "success":true
        };
        return successResponse;
      }
}

var setFailureResponse = function(err){
    var apiResponse = {
        "code":400,
        "message":"Bad Request or Internal Server Error. Please see data for inner exception.",
        "data":{"errMsg":err}
    }
    return apiResponse;
}
```

From your API call this methods to validate the paramters you require:

```
var validateFields = require('../validate');
var required = {
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email
    }

    var validation  = validateFields.validate(req, res, required);
    if (!validation.success) {
        return res.json(validation).end();
    }
```